# set_printoptions Not Suppressing As Expected

Tags: python, numpy

I had a look around and couldnt find a solution as to why the print options seems to correctly apply precision but ignores supression. For example

```
numpy.set_printoptions(precision =4, suppress=True)
```

When it returns data I get

```
Constant Ax^3 is 1.6047898918e-16
Constant Bx^2 is 1.0
Constant Cx is 7.4485117574e-15
Constant D is -4.0
```

the `suppress=True` function doesnt seem to be making the `e^` data become `0` as I want it.

The code I was testing is

```
if degree==3:
     print 'Testing third order polynomial model', '\n'  

#Polyfit Model Produces Expected Values Using Cubic Model
p = numpy.polyfit(xData,yData,3)
yp = numpy.polyval(p,xData)
A, B, C, D = numpy.polyfit(xData,yData,3)
print 'Constant Ax^3 is',A
print 'Constant Bx^2 is',B
print 'Constant Cx is',C
print 'Constant D is',D, '\n'
```

As you can tell im quite new to python but I cant see why it would not suppress the small values.

Comment: Did you check the type of `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`? `set_printoptions` only modifies the representation of *numpy's objects*, not python floats. In fact; `set_printoptions(suppress=True); print(np.array([1e-15]))` prints `array([ 0. ])`, but `np.float(1e-15)` prints `1e-15`.

Comment: Ah, I fixed it using "%.2f" %A, B, C for printing. Thanks!